# Python S2/S2sphere library - find all s2 cells on earth at a given level

Tags: python, gis

I am new to the python `s2sphere` library. At a given level, I want a list of *all* cell IDs. I tried using a rectangle bounded by the poles:

`region = s2sphere.LatLngRect(LatLng.from_degrees(-90,0),LatLng.from_degrees(90,0))`

but `region.area()` gives 0. I could take the union of many smaller rectangles, but that seems messy. Is there an elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I found that it can be done with two rectangles that span the two hemispheres. For level=0, an example is below:

`from s2sphere import *`

`region1=LatLngRect(LatLng.from_degrees(-90,0),LatLng.from_degrees(90,180))
r1=RegionCoverer()
r1.min_level,r1.max_level=(0,0)
cell_IDs1 = r1.get_covering(region1)`

`region2=LatLngRect(LatLng.from_degrees(-90,180),LatLng.from_degrees(90,0))
r2=RegionCoverer()
r2.min_level,r2.max_level=(0,0)
cell_IDs2 = r2.get_covering(region2)`

`all_cell_IDs = set(cell_IDs1) | set(cell_IDs2)`

The last line glues the hemispheres. Printing the cell lat-longs

`for i in all_cell_IDs: print i.to_lat_lng()`

gives:

`LatLng: 0.0,0.0
LatLng: 0.0,90.0
LatLng: -0.0,-180.0
LatLng: -0.0,-90.0
LatLng: 90.0,-180.0
LatLng: -90.0,0.0`

Which are the six sides of a cube. As expected, with level=1, there will be 24 cells.

Comment: As of s2sphere version 0.2.5 it also works with just one rectangle from (-90,-180) to (90,180).